# Using where in jenssegers/laravel-mongodb

Tags: laravel, mongodb, where-clause

I am using [jenssegers/laravel-mongodb](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb)  in laravel :

The structure of my data in the mongodb is as follows. Suppose there are 100 rows like this

[image: click show image]

I need a query to show me all the data whose `finance.selling_type` status  is 1

My attempt to write code

```
finances::where('finance.selling_types.$$status', 1)->get();
```

or

```
finances::where('finance.selling_types.*.status', 1)->get();
```

Comment: You can find the documents without the use of `*` or `$$` inside where condition    ```DB::collection('finances')->where('finance.sellingTypes.status',1)->get()```

Comment: This answer is wrong. Note that each head of object "selling_types"  is an object in itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to Oluwafemi Sule, I found the solution :

```
\DB::connection('mongodb')
            ->collection('finances')
            ->raw(function($collection) {
                return $collection->aggregate(
                    [
                        [
                            '$project' => [
                                'finance'=> [
                                    'selling_types'=> [
                                        '$objectToArray'=>  '$finance.selling_types'
                                    ]
                                ],
                              
                            ]
                        ],
                        [
                            '$unwind' => '$finance.selling_types'
                        ],
                        [
                            '$match'=> [
                                '$and' => [
                                    [
                                        'finance.selling_types.v.status' => [
                                            '$eq' => 1
                                        ],
                                    ],
                                ]
                            ]
                        ],

                    ]
                );
            });
```

Answer (score 3):

Use an [aggregation pipeline](https://mongoplayground.net/p/UkWrSc92Sjz).

Convert the objects embedded in selling_types to an array

```php
 $convertSellingTypesToArray = [
    '$project' => [
      'finance.selling_types' => [
        '$objectToArray' => '$finance.selling_types'
      ]
    ]
  ];
```

Then unwind the array to individual documents

```php
$sellingTypesAsDocuments =   [
    '$unwind' => '$finance.selling_types'
];
```

Filter where status is 1.

```php
$selectOnlyActiveStatus = [
    '$match' => [
      'finance.selling_types.v.status' => [
        '$eq' => 1
      ]
    ]
  ];
```

Convert selling_types back as an object.

```
$convertSellingTypesToObject = [
    '$project' => [
      'finance.selling_types' => [
        '$arrayToObject' => [
          [
            '$finance.selling_types'
          ],
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ];
```

```php
finances::raw()->aggregate([
  $convertSellingTypesToArray,
  $sellingTypesAsDocuments,
  $selectOnlyActiveStatus,
  $convertSellingTypesToObject,
])
```

> Note that you'll need to support pagination on the query